# My SQL query to find the max <= date with a matching primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that represent a historical data they both have a “src” column that represents the primary key in the primary table for that data.

For example

The primary tables would be

```
tbl_user        tbl_email
________        _________
user_pk         email_pk
username        email
email_pk        tstamp
tstamp
```

The history tables basically match the original with a "src" column indicating the source primary key record from the primary table.

```
tbl_user_hist                 tbl_email_hist
______________                ______________
user_pk                       email_pk
src_user_pk                   src_email_pk
username                      email
email_pk                      tstamp
tstamp
```

so if you had an email record of primary key 1 and you changed the email from bob@gmail.com to bob@hotmail.com and then again to bob@yahoo.com

your tbl_email_hist would look like this

```
email_pk     src_email_pk     email                tstamp
1                   1         bob@gmail.com        2012-01-01 04:06:28
2                   1         bob@hotmail.com      2012-03-01 04:06:28
3                   1         bob@yahoo.com        2012-07-01 04:06:28
```

And lets say that bobs original user name was  rsmith and then it was changed to bsmith and then back to rsmith2. But these user name changes do NOT NECESSARILY coincide with the timestamps of the email changes.

SO similarly the user history table would look like

```
tbl_user_hist
User_pk     src_user_pk     username    email_pk      tstamp
1           1               rsmith      1             2012-01-01 04:08:28
2           1               bsmith      1             2012-02-01 04:01:28
3           1               rsmith2     1             2012-05-01 04:05:28
```

SO what I WANT is to create a query that  will be able to find the correct email history record based on time stamp and the related email_pk record…meaning what was the value of that field at the time the user record was changed.
So in some way I need to find the record in the email hist table where the src_email_pk matches the email_pk in the user hist table but the tstamp for that email history record is the highest date while still <= the timestamp in the user table.

In the end my Data would look like this

```
Username     email              username_timestamp
Rsmith       bob@gmail.com      2012-01-01 04:08:28
Bsmith       bob@hotmail.com    2012-02-01 04:01:28
Rsmith2      bob@hotmail.com    2012-05-01 04:05:28
```

In other words reflecting the value of the email column at the time the username record was modified/created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I never answered this question..the above suggested answer wont work You get an error about having a Limit statement in a subclause though I think its the IN that is causing the problem.

This following sql statement solves the problem in MySQL

```
        Select u.username,
        (Select email
        FROM
        (SELECT tbl_user_hist.src_user_pk, tbl_user_hist.username, tbl_email_hist.email,
        tbl_email_hist.src_email_pk, tbl_email_hist.tstamp, tbl_user_hist.user_pk
        FROM  tbl_email_hist 
        INNER JOIN
        tbl_user_hist ON tbl_email_hist.src_email_pk = tbl_user_hist.email_pk AND
        tbl_email_hist.src_email_pk = tbl_user_hist.email_pk AND 
                              tbl_email_hist.tstamp <= tbl_user_hist.tstamp) as e
        where e.user_pk = u.user_pk ORDER BY e.tstamp desc Limit 1) as email,
        u.tstamp as username_tstamp 

        from tbl_user_hist as u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT username, email, tbl_user_hist.tstamp
FROM tbl_user_hist 
INNER JOIN tbl_email_hist AS tbl_email_hist1 ON tbl_user_hist.email_pk = tbl_email_hist1.src_email_pk 
WHERE src_user_pk = 1
AND tbl_email_hist1.email_pk IN (
    SELECT tbl_email_hist2.email_pk FROM tbl_email_hist2
    WHERE tbl_user_hist.email_pk = tbl_email_hist2.src_email_pk
    AND tbl_email_hist2.tstamp <= tbl_user_hist.tstamp
    ORDER BY tbl_email_hist2.tstamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: this query seems poorly optimized.

Comment: It is. But the good solution to do this in only one query goes though changing db schema denormalizing data, and storing fk to tbl_user_hist in tbl_user_hist.